# PowerShell equivalent to the Unix `which` command?

Tags: windows, unix, powershell, which

Does PowerShell have an equivalent to the `which` command found in most (if not all) Unix shells?

There are a number of times I'd like to know the location of something I'm running from the command line. In Unix I just do `which <command>`, and it tells me. I can't find an equivalent in PowerShell.

Comment: [Equivalent of *Nix 'which' command in PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63805/995714)

Answer (score 136, accepted):

This was asked and answered on Stack Overflow: *[Equivalent of *Nix 'which' command in PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63805/equivalent-of-nix-which-command-in-powershell)*

> The very first alias I made once I started customizing my profile in PowerShell was 'which'.
>
> New-Alias which get-command
>
> To add this to your profile, type this:
>
> "`nNew-Alias which get-command" | add-content $profile
>
> The `n at the start of the last line is to ensure it will start as a new line.

Answer (score 122):

As of PowerShell 3.0, you can do

```
(Get-Command cmd).Path
```

Which also has the benefit over vanilla Get-Command of returning a `System.String` so you get a clean *nixy single line output like you may be used to. Using the gcm alias, we can take it down to 11 characters.

```
(gcm cmd).Path
```

Comment: If `Get-Command` finds multiple results, it returns an array. Additionally, if the command it finds is not an executable, `Path` is undefined (`$null`). This makes the answer here impractical for general use without heavy modification. For a good example of both these cases, try `Get-Command where`.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it actually tells you what is the Powershell equivalent of the *NIX command `where` rather than teaching you how to set aliases on Powershell, which is not the title of the question.

Comment: @mastazi: But that fails for builtins, which is a regression compared to e.g. **zsh**'s `which`. (`where`, by the way, is actually a *Windows* utility that can do a number of different things, one of which *roughly* approximates searching for a command along the `PATH`.)  Also, there's **nothing** wrong with an answer that explains how to do what was asked *and* also another, slightly more involved thing built on that.

Answer (score 21):

Also answered in 2008: [Is there an equivalent of 'which' on the Windows command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304319/is-there-an-equivalent-of-which-on-windows)

Try the [`where`](http://ss64.com/nt/where.html) command if you've installed a Resource Kit.

Most important parts of the answer:

> Windows Server 2003 and later provide the `WHERE` command which does
>   some of what which does, though it matches all types of files, not
>   just executable commands.
>
> [snip]
>
> In Windows PowerShell you must type `where.exe`.

Answer (score 14):

I just do `where.exe <command>` in Powershell. This is the easiest approach that I know. The `.exe` part is important BTW.

Answer (score 7):

```
function which([string]$cmd) {gcm -ErrorAction "SilentlyContinue" $cmd | ft Definition}
```

Answer (score 7):

Try this: get-command [your command]

Answer (score 2):

Some great answers on this thread but I have found Powershell Alias's are a bit of a pain to re-define and functions are easier to write so I put this in my Powershell profile:

```
function global:which ([string]$command) {
  if (-not($command)) { throw "ERROR: Please supply a command name" }
  (Get-Command $command).Path
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Get-Command doesn't find .lnk or other types, just executable commands.

**To search $env:path for any file** (incl. .lnk) use

```
@(where.exe <file pattern> 2>$null)[0]
```

Returns empty string if nothing found, else full path of first encounter.

Answer (score 0):

In PowerShell 5.1 you could use

`Get-Command <command> | Format-Table Name, CommandType, DisplayName, Definition, Description, Version`

The path is in Definition column.